# Debugging Python script tools of ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2, python-script-tool

I recently got an script tool in a tbx file to play with.

I'd like to see how the tool runs in a debugger to get a better idea of how it works. I've tried several paths to this, but all of them seem to have failed:

1. Open in visual studio, or some other IDE: the windows explorer, of course, does not recognize .tbx as a container, and just displays garbage.
2. Right click the tool and use the "Debug" option: tool runs as usual, but I have no control over stepping, breakpoints, etc. I can't see the code as it is running.
3. Right click the tool and use the "Edit" button: python script opens in NotePad. There doesn't seem to be a way to choose another editor. Of course, notepad doesn't have a build or compile option, so I can't modify the code even to print output.
4. Copying the code into Visual Studio and running it there: when trying to run debug from ArcMap, I run into [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31811480/start-external-program-debugging-option-not-appearing-in-vs)

Comment: Right click on the python tool and hit edit.  See [here](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/A_quick_tour_of_creating_script_tools/001500000006000000/) to better understand script tools in an ArcToolbox.

Comment: Python never has to be compiled.

Comment: It never _has_ to be compiled, but it can be. I tried making obvious edits in notepad which should have thrown bugs, but the script did not change. Hence, I assumed the tool used a compiled version to run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how I typically debug/edit python files for python script tools in ArcMap ([and how ESRI suggests doing it](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Editing_script_tool_code/001500000009000000/))

> First, set your editor (such as PythonWin or Wing) in Geoprocessing >
>   Geoprocessing Options. Next, in the Catalog window, right-click your
>   tool and click Edit.
>
> Geoprocessing doesn't read your script code until you click OK on the
>   script tool dialog box or press ENTER while in the Python window.
>
> A common workflow when working with Python script tools is as follows:
>
> - Edit your script (using PythonWin or IDLE, for example) and save your    changes, but don't exit the editing application.
> - Run the script tool.
> - If need be, make more code changes, saving your edits but not exiting    the editing application.
> - Run the script tool again.
> - When you're satisfied that your script is working correctly, exit the editing application.

Comment: Sweet! Geoprocessing>Geoprocessing Options was just what I needed!

Answer (score 3):

To debug Python toolboxes I usually have a separate "debug.py" file in my project where I test just certain modules or code snippets.  The script is very simple, set up like this:

```
import os
import arcpy

def main():
    # code to test here, set break point and step thru

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

When a Python toolbox throws an error, I inspect the line number and copy the  function or method that contains the line in question into debug.py.  I hard code the various input parameter values that the tool would normally have, and step thru my code and find exactly what the error is.  Finally, I apply the changes to the Python toolbox .pyt file.  I am currently using Visual Studio code to run my Python scripts.

edit:

I want to add this link as well: [How to Debug Python Toolboxes in 3 Easy Steps](https://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2012/12/14/how-to-debug-python-toolboxes-in-3-easy-steps/).  This article shows another easy method of debugging a python toolbox simply by adding a main() method:

```
class MyToolbox(object):
    def __init__(self):

class MyTool(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.label = 'Tool 1'

def getParameterInfo(self):
    # parameters..
    return params

def execute(self, parameters, messages):
    # do stuff..
    return

def main():
    # set break point here, step thru
    tbx = MyToolbox()
    tool = MyTool()
    tool.execute(tool.getParameterInfo(), None)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```